# Rails mapping by max size and loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my rails application I'm looking to display in a table some results mapping by max size.

**Controller**

```
@max_length = [@result.generals, @result.measurements.in_groups_of(3)].map(&:size).max
```

The problem i'm facing is my `@result.measurement` has 3 dates for each measurement in which I want to display across the row.

This is what I'm looking to achieve:

[image]

But with the code below, this is my result - It stops at the first date:

[image]

How can I go about looping the `@result.measurements`?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">General</th>
        <th colspan="6">Measurements</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td>Town</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Length</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Length</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Length</td>
    </tr>
    <% @max_length.times do |data| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= @result.generals.[data].try(:number) %></td>
        <td><%= @result.generals.[data].try(:town) %></td>
        <td><%= @result.measurements.[data].try(:date) %></td>
        <td><%= @result.measurements.[data].try(:length) %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
```

Comment: What is `@result.measurements`? What is `@result.generals`? It's hard to understand your problem without knowing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing exactly what you are asking it to do: to display a single td for the measurements. In order to have three lots of the columns, you need to loop over the data eg something like:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">General</th>
    <th colspan="6">Measurements</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Number</td>
    <td>Town</td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Length</td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Length</td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Length</td>
</tr>
<% @result.measurements.in_groups_of(3).each do |general, measurements| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= general.try(:number) %></td>
    <td><%= general.try(:town) %></td>
    <% measurements.each do |m|
      <td><%= m.try(:date) %></td>
      <td><%= m.try(:length) %></td>
    <% end %>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Note: of course I have not bug-tested this - it will probably not work exactly as is - because I do not have a copy of your data (and you have not provided an example) so you'll need to adapt what I've written to what you have so that it works...

At present I don't know how your general relates to your measurements.

can you provide some example data that you would expect to be returned by the fetching-code and I can adapt this example to fit.